# How can I program a mixture model with two Gaussian dimensions and one exponential dimension?

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis

I have been working with finite mixture models for clustering in multiple dimensions. I'd like to extend a model to 3-dimensional data, where two dimensions are thought to be normally distributed, and the third is assumed to be exponential.

I've been working in MATLAB, but I have seen there are several R packages that may be of use also. Can someone help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You've specified the marginal distributions, but not the joint distribution. Unless you're assuming the three dimensions are independent there's not enough info for anybody to say anything meaningful.

Comment: I am assuming independence, so the joint is the product of the marginals.

Comment: Then all you need to do is generate the three RVs independently.  Both R and Matlab can do that easily.